# Highcharts - how to do a responsive pie chart when the texts of the labels are long

Tags: highcharts

I need to do a responsive pie chart with a drilldown on the green area. The text of the labels are too long so in mobile devices it appears like this:
[image]

As you can see the texts are cut. 
How can I make these texts appear fully in responsive. Please find code below. TIA

```js
Highcharts.chart('recoveryGraf', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: ['#005eb8','#56b6cc','#8bc540'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Potential for further recovery',
            y: 6,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Non-recoverable<br>(e.g. tissue,wallpaper,etc)',
            y: 22,
            drilldown: null
        }, {
            name: 'Recycled',
            y: 72,
            drilldown: 'Recycleds'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Recycleds',
            id: 'Recycleds',
            colors: ['#57a133','#8bc540'],
            data: [
                ['Exported', 16],
                ['Used Europe', 84]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="recoveryGraf"></div>
```

Comment: To prevent data labels from being cut, you can set `crop` with false and `overflow` with 'none' (http://jsfiddle.net/vbrdtksh/). You could also decrease `distance` (http://jsfiddle.net/q7tc6hwo/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

```
responsive: {
  rules: [{
   condition: {
     maxWidth: 300
    },
   chartOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
     pie: {
      dataLabels: {
       enabled: false
       // add your costume code here
       }
     }
   }
  }
}]
}
```